# Django Rest Framework - to_internal_value Error Inconsistency

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I have a model, User, in which the primary unique field is email.  I have a separate Organization model which allows users to map to organizations through a many-to-many mapping.

I want the serializer to allow users to be created if they have an existing email but no organization association (organization is taken from the user making the request so is not in the payload).

The standard ModelSerializer includes a check against the field in to_internal_value().  I am consequently trying to override it like so:

```
    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        """
        Dict of native values <- Dict of primitive datatypes.
        """
        fields = self._writable_fields
        for field in fields:
            validate_method = getattr(self, 'validate_' + field.field_name, None)
            primitive_value = field.get_value(data)
            try:
                if validate_method == self.validate_email:
                    if User.objects.filter(email=primitive_value).exists():
                        if not self.active_organization.members.filter(email=primitive_value).exists():
                            continue
                else:
                    validated_value = field.run_validation(primitive_value)
                    if validate_method is not None:
                        validated_value = validate_method(validated_value)
            except ValidationError as exc:
                errors[field.field_name] = exc.detail
            except DjangoValidationError as exc:
                errors[field.field_name] = get_error_detail(exc)
            except SkipField:
                pass
            else:
                set_value(ret, field.source_attrs, validated_value)
        return super().to_internal_value(data)
```

This works, but the error that is returned if the object already has a record in User and Organization does not correctly map as a dictionary.  For example, the validation error shows this:

`[ErrorDetail(string='User with this Email already exists.', code='unique')]`

Instead of what it should show, this:

`{'email': [ErrorDetail(string='User with this Email already exists.', code='unique')]}`

I tested by overriding the method and trying both my custom called code vs. the original, and it replicates the above findings:

```
    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        """
        Dict of native values <- Dict of primitive datatypes.
        """
        try:
            print('trying custom')
            for field in self._writable_fields:
                if field.field_name == 'email':
                    print(field.run_validation)
                    validated_value = field.run_validation(field.get_value(data))
        except Exception as e:
            print('error custom')
            print(str(e))

        try:
            print('Trying original')
            value = super().to_internal_value(data)
        except Exception as e:
            print('Exception - original')
            print(str(e))
```

Output:

```
trying custom
<bound method CharField.run_validation of EmailField(max_length=254, validators=[<UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())>])>
error custom
[ErrorDetail(string='User with this Email already exists.', code='unique')]

Trying original
Exception - original
{'email': [ErrorDetail(string='User with this Email already exists.', code='unique')]}
```

Can anyone help me understand why this is happening please?  I'm really stuck as to how this is happening.

Comment: How do you want to create User with email which already exist ? If you have email unique=True on your User model it is impossible.

Comment: That's why I'm trying this. Basically I check to see if the user already exists in this to_internal_value() call. If they do && they exist for the organization, I want to return the normal failure message. If they exist as only email and not org, the data gets fed to the create() method in which I don't create the email but add them to the organization: Organization.members.add(User.objects.get(email=email)).

The weird thing is, when I override the to_internal_value method, the error does not return as a dictionary with 'email' as the key.

Comment: I will help you in the next half of the day. Basically try to use validate_email method in serializer (where you can validate email, dont override to_internal_value method !), and try to use self.context['request'].user (in serializer) .. to get active organization.

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to figure out why exactly the errors generated by `to_internal_value(self, data)` change when I copy the code from the underlying ModelSerializer vs calling super().  However, I did find a kind-of hackish workaround.

Because I strip out all the other related info (nested serializers, kind of) before hand, I'm really just worried about the email.  Therefore, I traverse the _writable_fields twice: the first time I look for an existing email where it isn't in the organization. If those conditions are true, I return a dictionary and proceed to the create() method.  If they fail, I call super.  So far this seems to work.  Here is my simplified class.

```
    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        """
        Dict of native values <- Dict of primitive datatypes.
        """
        try:
            for field in self._writable_fields:
                if field.field_name == 'email':
                    primitive_value = field.get_value(data)
                    validator = EmailValidator()
                    validator(primitive_value)
                    if User.objects.filter(email=primitive_value).exists():
                        if not self.active_organization.members.filter(email=primitive_value).exists():
                            self.email_already_exists = True
                            return {'email': primitive_value}
        except:
            pass

        return super().to_internal_value(data)
```

For reference, this is the complete ViewSet and Serializer I'm using:

```
class AdminUsersSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """User serializer for the admin user view"""
    groups = GenericGroupSerializer(source='group_set', many=True, required=False)
    permission_sets = GenericPermissionSetSerializer(source='permissionset_set', many=True, required=False)
    active_organization = None
    email_already_exists = False

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['pk', 'email', 'groups', 'permission_sets']  # , 'permissions']

    def set_active_organization(self, organization):
        self.active_organization = organization

    def create(self, validated_data):
        if not self.email_already_exists:
            user = User.objects.create(
                email=validated_data['email']
            )
            user.set_password(None)
            user.save()
        else:
            user = User.objects.get(email=validated_data['email'])
        return user

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        """
        Dict of native values <- Dict of primitive datatypes.
        """
        try:
            for field in self._writable_fields:
                if field.field_name == 'email':
                    primitive_value = field.get_value(data)
                    validator = EmailValidator()
                    validator(primitive_value)
                    if User.objects.filter(email=primitive_value).exists():
                        if not self.active_organization.members.filter(email=primitive_value).exists():
                            self.email_already_exists = True
                            return {'email': primitive_value}
        except:
            pass

        return super().to_internal_value(data)

class AdminUsersViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AdminUsersSerializer
    permission_classes = [account_permissions.IsAdminRequired]
    http_method_names = ['get', 'post']
    active_organization = None

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.active_organization = self.request.user.activeorganization.organization
        groups = None
        permission_sets = None
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.set_active_organization(self.active_organization)
        if 'groups' in serializer.initial_data:
            if serializer.initial_data.get('groups'):
                groups = serializer.initial_data.pop('groups')
            else:
                serializer.initial_data.pop('groups')
        if 'permission_sets' in serializer.initial_data:
            if serializer.initial_data.get('permission_sets'):
                permission_sets = serializer.initial_data.pop('permission_sets')
            else:
                serializer.initial_data.pop('permission_sets')
        # Normal method functions
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        # Created user
        user = User.objects.get(email=serializer.data['email'])
        # Add user to organization
        self.active_organization.members.add(user)
        # Make sure to format the ajax groups data properly
        if groups:
            try:
                group = Group.objects.get(
                    id=groups,
                    organization=self.active_organization
                )
                group.members.add(user)
            except:
                pass
        if permission_sets:
            try:
                permission_set = PermissionSet.objects.get(
                    id=permission_sets,
                    organization=self.active_organization
                )
                permission_set.members.add(user)
            except:
                pass
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.queryset.filter(
            userorganizationmembership__organization=self.request.user.activeorganization.organization
        ).all()
```

It does feel hackish, but it seems to be getting the job done.